# How to I prevent creation of new MongoDB databases from slowing down my tests?

Tags: mongodb

Before each of my functional tests, I drop the test database and "recreate" it by setting up the indexes again. This is causing every small test to take more than a second.

In the log, these lines show up:

```
2015-01-27T17:24:38.129+0100 [initandlisten] connection accepted from anonymous unix socket #4 (1 connection now open)
2015-01-27T17:24:38.141+0100 [conn4] dropDatabase test starting
2015-01-27T17:24:38.153+0100 [conn4] removeJournalFiles
2015-01-27T17:24:38.170+0100 [conn4] dropDatabase test finished
2015-01-27T17:24:38.171+0100 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile /home/tomas/mongodb/data/test.ns, filling with zeroes...
2015-01-27T17:24:38.908+0100 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile /home/tomas/mongodb/data/test.ns, size: 16MB,  took 0.736 secs
2015-01-27T17:24:38.908+0100 [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile /home/tomas/mongodb/data/test.0, filling with zeroes...
2015-01-27T17:24:38.914+0100 [FileAllocator] done allocating datafile /home/tomas/mongodb/data/test.0, size: 64MB,  took 0.005 secs
```

Notice that allocating a new data file for the database "took 0.736 secs". Is there any way I can reduce or avoid that?

I tried using `--noprealloc`, but it made no difference.

Answer (score 2):

I found a nice answer while I was writing this question. I Googled whether it was possible to run MongoDB entirely in RAM or not, and it turns out it's really easy (I followed [this guide](http://edgystuff.tumblr.com/post/49304254688/how-to-use-mongodb-as-a-pure-in-memory-db-redis).)

I created a media folder for a RAM disk:

```
sudo mkdir /media/ramfs
sudo chmod 777 /media/ramfs
```

Mounted a RAM disk onto the folder:

```
sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=128M tmpfs /media/ramfs/
```

Created a directory for MongoDB:

```
mkdir /media/ramfs/mongodata
```

And started MongoDB with this script (`mongo-testing`):

```
mongod \
    --dbpath=/media/ramfs/mongodata \
    --bind_ip=127.0.0.1 \
    --port=9701 \
    --pidfilepath=$HOME/mongodb/mongodb.pid \
    --unixSocketPrefix=$HOME/mongodb \
    --noprealloc \
    --nojournal \
    --smallfiles \
    $*
```

My test suite time was reduced from almost 4 seconds to 0.07 seconds.

Now I'm looking into running two instances of MongoDB at once and getting my test suite to use the instance running on a RAM disk, but that's a separate topic.